# How to write text along a line or curve in R?

Tags: r, graph, plot, lm

I have a data-set, and I am trying to fit a linear model using `lm()`. That part is straight forward.

I can also plot this fit to a graph of the scatter plot using `abline( lm( x ~ y ) )`.

But now I want to write the parameters of the fit such as `adjusted r-squared` along the line.
So that if I hover plot different data-sets and their respective fits, I should be able to print some of the values for the fit along the line.

Is it possible to do this in R.

Comment: Start [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7549694/324364) and then you'll just need to calculate the angle of the line and adjust the position you place the text at based on the some of the model's fitted values.

Comment: @joran I looked at it, and getting to display the information as given in that graph is relatively straight forward.  I am still thinking, but thought that collective wisdom might be better at solving this problem.

Comment: [Here is a very similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11767484/how-to-annotate-a-reference-line-at-the-same-angle-as-the-reference-line-itself/11767837#11767837) that received several good answers.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's easy to do for straight lines, a curve is trickier, possibly simpler with monospaced fonts.  The basic technique would be to just convert your linear equation such that you could derive a polar expression with an angle.  Use that angle to set the angle for the text in the `text` command using the `srt` argument (from graphic parameters).

For a curve it would be a bit more tricky (perhaps simplified by non-proportional fonts).  You need to work out vectors for each letter with an angle and then the width of each character (using `strwidth`).  You'd generate a vector of angles and positions for your characters and loop through them calling `text`.  You need a loop here because `text` cannot take a vector for the `srt` argument.